# Parse HTML com Jsoup - Java

Tags: java, parse, jsoup

Estou estudandoa biblioteca Jsoup e peguei o exemplo mais básico do site e tentei montar algo simples, porém tenho este erro, que não me permite executar o código:

> Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by
>   implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

O que este erro quer dizer e como resolvê-lo? Ja pesquisei bastante mas as respostas são vagas.

```
package estudandoJsoup;


import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Parse {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();
    String title = doc.title();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O exemplo que eles disponibilizam lá serve para você entender melhor a simplicidade do JSoup para *parsear* um documento html, mas você **precisa** tratar as falhas que podem ocorrer.

Uma forma de inicializar os atributos `doc` e `title` é utilizando o construtor da sua classe `Parse`:

```
package estudandoJsoup;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Parse {
    Document doc;
    String title;

    public Parse(){
        try  {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();
            title = doc.title();
        } catch(IOException err){
            /* Tratamento */
        }
    }
}
```